# Display content after a full-screen background image,using CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to display content after(below the image,as we scroll down) a full-screen background image.I have decided to use the CSS3 technique :

```
body{ 
background: url('images/body-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the codepen : [Link](http://codepen.io/Amit-Kolambikar/pen/batKk)

What I did in the pen above is that :

```
.content{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header>My title</header>
    <div class="content">My content starts from here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is Which is the best way to style the content after(below the image,as we scroll down) the background image ?

Comment: By after you mean in the context of time - 1st load style for background then load the context. Or you mean to have the content behind the background actually? :D.. Having some troubles opening the codepen, maybe if you could post the html too.

Comment: Like Ms.Nobody said, please clarify what you mean with "after". Do you mean "on top of the background", e.g. in foreground?

Comment: Question edited.I meant below the background image as you scroll down,content should begin with white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery

```
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();
$("body").css("background-size",winH + "px " + winW + "px" );
```

Comment: I wanted the background to cover the entire screen

Comment: @user199917 try this.